# I am not able to upload file using php?

Tags: php

I am getting the following warning

```
Warning: copy(file.txt) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such
file or directory in /users/abc/pantry/public_html/index.php on line 5
Could not copy file!

<?php

if ($_FILES['file']['name'] != "") {
    copy($_FILES['file']['name'], "/users/abc/pantry/public_html/temp/") or die("Could not copy file!");
} else {
    die("No file specified!");
}
?>
```

Even though the folder temp is present with 777 permission .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need specify file name here:

```
"/users/abc/pantry/public_html/temp/" . $_FILES['file']['name']
```

Also you should use absolute path to uploaded file:

`$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

Comment: the OP's problem is also that php can't find the temporary name of the uploaded file on server

Answer (score 2):

Change the line with the copy function to

```
copy( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "/users/abc/pantry/public_html/temp/" ) or
          die( "Could not copy file!");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
copy( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "/users/abc/pantry/public_html/temp/{$_FILES['file']['name']}" )
```

In fact:

`$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` contains the temporary name of the file on the server;

`$_FILES['file']['name']` contains the original name of the uploaded file.

I suggest you to take a look here: http://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file

**Update**: as suggested by Pitchinnate, you should also set up some filename checks to avoid file overwriting.
Additionally, it's not a very good idea to keep permissions to 777

Comment: sure, but we're not discussing about security on this specific answer, there would be a lot to talk about..

Comment: Agreed that's why I didn't down vote I was just throwing out a word of caution.

Answer (score 1):

As it say Barif you have to especify the new new of the file, here is the example from php official documentation

```
<?php
$archivo = 'ejemplo.txt';
$nuevo_archivo = 'ejemplo.txt.bak';

if (!copy($archivo, $nuevo_archivo)) {
    echo "Error al copiar $archivo...\n";
}
?>
```